# Swift variable not updating depending on calling class

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit

Swift newb here. The ObservableObject seems to be creating separate instances of a variable when updated. Updating the count variable from ContentView adds to a separate variable than updating the count variable from GameScene (see console log output).

I *think* this is because I'm creating a new instance in GameScene with PlayerStats() but haven't figured a way around.

What is the simplest way to have a single source of truth for variables - that is, both the View and the SKScene can read and update the variable(s)? Searching hasn't gotten me further than cryptic error messages (as said, newb) so thanks in advance for any info.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var playerstats:PlayerStats
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 700)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        return scene
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SpriteView(scene: self.scene)
                .frame(width: 400, height: 700)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }

        Text("Count : \(playerstats.count)")
        Button("add to count") {
            playerstats.addCount(newcount: 12)
        }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
    }
}
```

The class

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    let playerstats:PlayerStats = PlayerStats()// (I've tried PlayerStats?)

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.backgroundColor = .blue
        let count = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Times New Roman")
        count.text = String(playerstats.count)
        count.fontSize = 65
        count.fontColor = SKColor.green
        count.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
        addChild(count)
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        playerstats.addCount(newcount: Int(40))
    }
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        
    }
}
```

The observable object

```
class PlayerStats:ObservableObject {
    @Published var count:Int = 1
    func addCount(newcount: Int) {
        print(newcount)
        print("in add")
        count += newcount
        print(count)
    }
}
```

The console output

```
12 // from ContentView
in add
13
40 // from GameScene
in add
41
12 // from ContentView
in add
25
40 // from GameScene
in add
81
```

Comment: Every time you call PlayerStats() you create a different instance, one does not know about the other. The EnvironmentObject instance is in no way connected with the GameScene instance. You can pass as an argument but you’ll need to reorganize.

Comment: Also, a new scene is created on every refresh of the view. The `GameScene` should be stored somewhere persistent. I think `@State` is fine, but some will argue that state should never be used for reference types. Another option is to store it in an `ObservableObject`

Comment: Have a look at this  **official** link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [Monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)  
In essence, you have to declare `@StateObject var playerstats = PlayerStats()` in your views hierarchy (not elsewhere, only in a View), 
and pass this **one** model to other views and to `GameScene`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks for getting back and for supporting Ukraine. I reread the Apple doc page and have been searching but haven't found how to pass a model into a class (as opposed to a view). Thinking I have to reorganize but still wandering in the dark. Thanks for any further info or pointers.

Comment: You could try making `PlayerStats` a singleton as well as an `ObservableObject`. For example, 
`class PlayerStats:ObservableObject {     static let shared = PlayerStats() ...   }` and using that in your `GameScene` class, `PlayerStats.shared`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Hey thanks! Singleton and the variable updates correctly - per console log - but the update isn't seen in ContentView : Text("Fuel : \(PlayerStats.shared.fuel)") keeps displaying the initial value. I'll keep digging. Thank you for the pointer!

Comment: In `ContentView` keep using the ObservableObject `playerstats`, not the singleton.

Comment: Note, you may need to declare `@StateObject var playerstats = PlayerStats.shared` in your view hierarchy, to get both an observable object and a singleton. Note, I have not tested any of this.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine That was it thanks! I'm still mystified as I don't reference the (lowercase) playerstats anywhere but declaring it updates the text field. Anyone arriving here -  (at)StateObject var playerstats = PlayerStats.shared and Text("Fuel : \(PlayerStats.shared.fuel)") is working.

Answer (score 0):

What is working is declaring a Singleton.

```
class PlayerStats:ObservableObject {
    static let shared = PlayerStats()
    @Published var fuel:Int = 1
    func addFuel(newfuel: Int) {
        print("in add")
        fuel += newfuel
        print(fuel)
    }
}
```

and declaring

```
@StateObject var playerstats = PlayerStats.shared
```

in ContentView. And using .shared in the text

```
Text("Fuel : \(PlayerStats.shared.fuel)")
```

Big thanks to workingdogsupportUkraine in the comments.